# Type 'Object' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I am trying to run a MERN application to validate what it has, but it is sending me this error in several files.

Error: **Type 'CatalogType' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'.
Type 'CatalogType' is missing the following properties from type 'Document': $ignore, $isDefault, $isDeleted, $isEmpty, and 45 more.ts(2344)**

[image]

My code:

```
const {
      Types: { ObjectId },
    } = Schema;
    
    export interface CatalogType {
      _id: any;
      code: string;
      description: string;
      version: number;
    }
    
export interface CatalogDocumentType extends Document,CatalogType{
      _id: number;
    }
    
export const schema = new Schema<CatalogType>(
      {
        id: {
          type: ObjectId,
        },
        code: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        description: {
          type: String,
          required: false,
        },
        version: {
          type: Number,
          required: false,
        },
      },
      {
        timestamps: {
          currentTime: () => new TimeZone().getLocaleCSTfromGMT(),
        },
      },
    );
    
export const Model = model<CatalogDocumentType>('Catalog', schema);
```

Help me, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic parameters of generic class `Schema` has generic constraint, see [index.d.ts](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/index.d.ts#L1042).

```
class Schema<DocType extends Document = Document, M extends Model<DocType> = Model<DocType>> extends events.EventEmitter {/**..*/}
```

The generic parameter `DocType` Must meet `Document` type constraints. So the correct way is:

```
import { Schema, model, Document, Model } from 'mongoose';

const {
  Types: { ObjectId },
} = Schema;

export interface CatalogTypeDocument extends Document {
  _id: number;
  code: string;
  description: string;
  version: number;
}

export interface CatalogTypeModel extends Model<CatalogTypeDocument> {}

export const schema = new Schema<CatalogTypeDocument>({
  id: {
    type: ObjectId,
  },
  code: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  version: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
  },
});

export const CatalogTypeModel = model<CatalogTypeDocument, CatalogTypeModel>('Catalog', schema);
```

For more info, see [mongoosejs-typescript-docs](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/mongoose#mongoosejs-typescript-docs)

package versions:

```json
"mongoose": "^5.11.9",
"@types/mongoose": "^5.10.3",
"typescript": "^3.7.2"
```